# Method chaining with R

Tags: r, method-chaining

Is it possible to chain functions in R?

Sample data:

```
m <- matrix(c(1:10, 11:20), nrow = 10, ncol = 2)
```

For example, I would like to replace the following statements below:

```
step1 <- mean(m)
step2 <- sum(step1)
res <- step2
```

Or,

```
res <- sum(mean(m))
```

With something like this :

```
res <- m@mean()@sum()
```

In some cases, that would clarify my code considerably.

EDIT1
This is a dummy example. I randomly picked 'sum' and 'mean'.

Ben has given a first piece of answer using %@% however, it prevents from using extra arguments within functions :

```
m %@% function1(arg1, arg2) %@% function2(arg1, arg2)
```

How can I work around that ?

EDIT2
Adding an example

```
require(xts)
require(PerformanceAnalytics)
xts.ts <- xts(rnorm(231),as.Date(13514:13744,origin="1970-01-01"))
plot(na.omit(lag( rollapply(xts.ts, width=rolling.per-1, FUN= function(x){sqrt(var(x))*sqrt(252)}), k=1)), main = "Dummy Example")
```

This example seems to work fine with Charles solution :

```
`%@%` <- function(x, f) eval.parent(as.call(append(as.list(substitute(f)), list(x), 1)))
xts.ts %@% rollapply( width = rolling.per-1, FUN= function(x) x%@%var%@%sqrt * sqrt(252) ) %@% lag( k=1) %@% na.omit %@% plot(main = "Dummy Example")
```

Less important to my case, but woth mentioning, the following statment fails with Charles's solution :

```
 xts.ts %@% names <- 'ts name'
```

Comment: What's wrong with `res <- sum(mean(m))`?

Comment: Nothing, but it doesn't make to much sense to take the `sum` of a length 1 vector (which is what is returned by `mean` on a matrix).

Comment: Although it will be going away "soon", there is still a `mean.data.frame` function that returns a vector.

Comment: With a lot of function and arguments, I found it heavy where IMO  method chaining may improves readability and reduces the amount of source code. But you're right, nothing wrong with res <- sum(mean(m))

Comment: FYI this style of programming is called point-free (or sometimes pointless!). There are a few notes on it at https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Function-operators#function-composition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a similar vein to Ben's answer, but allowing arguments:

```
`%@%` <- function(x, f) eval.parent(as.call(append(as.list(substitute(f)), list(x), 1)))

x %@% mean %@% sqr # => 6.25
c(1, 2, NA, 3, 4) %@% mean(na.rm=T) %@% sqr # => 6.25
m %@% colMeans() %@% sum() # => 21
```

Comment: To get the last one to work you'd need to use either `names<-` or `setNames`, eg `xts.ts %@% setNames('ts name')`, as `<-` has special handling for lhs function call that won't work here.

Comment: I hadn't seen this before.  It's super-clever.  I'd be very afraid to use it in production code because of the chances that it would be fragile ...

Comment: I wouldn't want to use this in code - production or otherwise! Regardless of whether this is a good idea or not, what I like about R is that this kind of thing is possible. I can see how it would look more familiar to someone who is used to the common OO `object.verb()` instead of R's `verb(object)`.

Answer (score 12):

Try the functional package:

```
library(functional)
squared <- function(x)x*x
Compose(sum, squared)(m)
## [1] 44100
squared(sum(m))
## [1] 44100
```

EDIT:

Regarding the question in the comments of another response about arguments here is an example of composing with arguments.  `Curry` is also from the functional package:

```
addn <- function(n, x) x + n
Compose(Curry(addn, 1), squared)(10)
## [1] 121
squared(addn(1, 10))
## [1] 121
```

EDIT 2:

Regarding question about debugging, `debug` works if the function is curried.  If its not already curried then wrap it in `Curry` :

```
# this works since addn is curried
debug(addn)
Compose(Curry(addn, 1), squared)(10)

# to debug squared put it in a Curry -- so this works:
debug(squared)
Compose(Curry(addn, 1), Curry(squared))(10)
```

Comment: I thought the gsubfn-package could do something like that, at least the postfix syntax of env@fn?

Comment: @DWin, Good point.  In gsubfn we could do this: `Compose(fn$identity(~ addn(1, x)), squared)(10)` .  Of course even without gsubfn we could do this: `Compose(function(x) addn(1, x), squared)(10)`

Comment: @G.Grothendieck, it works but I do not think it gives you the usual advantages of fluent interface (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) as some other object oriented languages would. Furthermore, I believe it does not make easy to debbug part of a statment.

Comment: @Sam, `debug` works if function is in a `Curry`.  See `EDIT 2` .

Answer (score 9):

Sort of, but I think it's un-idiomatic and maybe fragile/not a good idea.  (This is implied, I think, by @RichieCotton's comment above.)

From http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html :

> 10.3.4 Special operators
>
> R allows user-defined infix operators. These have the form of a string of characters delimited by the ‘%’ character. The string can
>   contain any printable character except ‘%’. The escape sequences for
>   strings do not apply here.
>
> Note that the following operators are predefined
>
> ```
>  %% %*% %/% %in% %o% %x%
> ```

```
"%@%" <- function(x,f) {
    f(x)
}

sqr <- function(x) x^2
x <- 1:4

x %@% mean  ## 2.5
x %@% mean %@% sqr  ## 6.25
x %@% (mean %@% sqr)  ## fails
```

Given `m` as defined above -- maybe what you had in mind?

```
 m %@% colMeans %@% sum  ## 21
```

Notes:

- your example is a bit funny, because `mean(x)` always returns a scalar (i.e. a length-1 vector), so `sum(mean(x))` is always going to be the same as `mean(x)`
- the infix operators have to be surrounded by `%`, so you can't have anything as compact as a single symbol (and `%%` is taken already).
- this sort of chaining is non-associative, which worries me -- it seems that the examples above work, so R is (apparently) evaluating left-to-right, but I don't know that that's guaranteed ...

**edit**: the question now asks how additional arguments can be incorporated.  I don't think the syntax suggested (`x %@% fun1(arg1) %@% fun2(arg2)`) will work without some serious magic.  This is the closest I can get at the moment -- creating a wrapper function that creates a modified version of the original function.

```
F <- function(f,...) {
    function(x) {
        f(x,...)
    }
}
```

Testing:

```
pow <- function(x,b=2) { x^b }
sqr <- function(x) x^2
x <- 1:4

x %@% F(mean,na.rm=TRUE)  ## 2.5
x %@% F(mean,na.rm=TRUE) %@% F(pow,3)  ## 16.25
```

(Note that I have used `F` as a function here, which may be dicey in some situations because it overwrites the `F==FALSE` shortcut)

Comment: Seems to be a work around but it may just do the trick fine! How would you suggest to modify the %@% operator so I can add arguments ? For instance : m %@% function1(arg1, arg2) % function2(arg1, arg2)

Comment: What is with `"%@%" <- function(f,...) f(...)`? With this all arguments should be passed to `f`, even named arguments. (note: untested)

Comment: @Sam, can you give me an specific example of what you want to do and what results it should produce?  Your syntax won't work exactly as written because `function1(arg1,arg2)` is not in general a function. I think @Henrik's idea may not work, because we have to be careful to keep the arguments in the right order ... `f` should be the *second* argument in order to get the operation in the correct left-to-right order ...

Comment: @Henrik I was not able to use your function, there is something I do not understand.

Comment: @Ben : the argument order may be an issue. I will edit my question to add an example.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the `magrittr` package. It has a "pipe" operator that takes the result of one function and passes it in as an argument to the next:

```
m <- matrix(c(1:10, 11:20), nrow = 10, ncol = 2)

m %>% mean %>% sum
```

Ceci n'est pas un pipe!