# Apply a set of functions to an object

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a set of objects `df$data` and a set of rules to be applied on every object `df$rules`.

```
df <- data.frame(
  data = c(1,2,3),
  rules = c("rule1", "rule1, rule2, rule3", "rule3, rule2"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)
```

The rules are

```
rule1 <- function(data) {
  data * 2
}

rule2 <- function(data) {
  data + 1
}

rule3 <- function(data) {
  data ^ 3
}
```

For every row in the dataframe I want to apply all the rules specified in the `rules` column. The rules should be applied in series.

What I figured out:

```
apply_rules <- function(data, rules) {
  for (i in 1:length(data)) {
    rules_now <- unlist(strsplit(rules[i], ", "))
    for (j in 1:length(rules_now)) {
      data[i] <- apply_rule(data[i], rules_now[j])
    }
  }
  return(data)
}

apply_rule <- function(data, rule) {
  return(sapply(data, rule))
}


apply_rules(df$data, df$rules)
# [1]   2 125  28
```

Although this works I'm pretty sure there must be more elegant solutions. On SO I could find lot's of stuff about the `apply`-functions and also one [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979206/apply-many-functions-to-one-vector/30979677#30979677) about applying many functions to a vector and something about [chaining functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330659/method-chaining-with-r/11331637#11331637). The `Compose` idea looks promising but I couldn't figure out how to make a call to `Compose` with my rules as string. (`parse()` didn't work..)

Any hints?

Comment: Try `mutate` function from `tidyverse` packages. https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html

Comment: @TitoSanz: thanks. I just don't see how this helps. How should I call `mutate` with the rules specified in `df$rules`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some good answers already but throw in another option - build a pipe chain as a string then evaluate it. For example - for row 1 - `eval(parse(text = "1 %>% rule1"))` gives 2

```
eval_chain <- function(df) {
    eval(parse(text = paste(c(df$data, unlist(strsplit(df$rules, ", "))), collapse=" %>% ")))
}

df$value <- sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) df[i, ] %>% eval_chain)
  # data               rules value
# 1    1               rule1     2
# 2    2 rule1, rule2, rule3   125
# 3    3        rule3, rule2    28
```

Comment: Be careful with runtime. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37827946/5784831)

Answer (score 2):

You can use  `mapply` and `Reduce` together with `mget` in this case.

```
mapply(function(d,r) Reduce(function(lhs,rhs) rhs(lhs),
                            c(d,mget(strsplit(r,", ")[[1]],envir = globalenv())))
       ,df$data
       ,df$rules)

# [1] 2 125  28
```

You might have to adjust the `envir` argument of `mget` to your specific case. It would probably be more robust to explicitly pass the environment where your rules are defined to `mget`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to change the approach a little (expressions will only make things worse in this case):

```
df <- data.frame(
  data = c(1,2,3),
  rules = c("rule1", "rule1, rule2, rule3", "rule3, rule2"),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# list of functions
fun_list <- list(
  rule1 = function(x) x*2,
  rule2 = function(x) x+1,
  rule3 = function(x) x^3
)

# function to call list of functions
call_funs <- function(x, fun_vec) {
  for (i in seq_along(fun_vec)) {
    x <- fun_list[[fun_vec[[i]]]](x)
  }
  x
}

(want <- unlist(Map(call_funs, df$data, strsplit(gsub(" ", "", df$rules), ","))))    
#   2 125  28
```